# saving an image to file after processing opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to save an image after I have processed it but unfortunately I am getting an exception. It is running all the lines except the `imwrite` command (last command on code), and it's throwing this exception:

```
Unhandled exception at at 0x000007FEFD0D940D in histogram.exe: 
   Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000000001DF720.
```

How can I fix this error, and what is causing it?

The code I'm using:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])       
{ 
    ///Loading image to IplImage 
    //IplImage *img=cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
    IplImage *img;
    img = cvLoadImage("phidza.JPG",1);
    cvShowImage("Ipl",img); 
    ///converting IplImage to cv::Mat
    Mat image=cvarrToMat(img); 
    imshow("Mat",image); 
    //std::cout<<"size: " << image.size() .height<< " , "
        // << image.size().width << std::endl ;
    if (image.empty())
    {
        cout << "Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2GRAY); //change the color image to grayscale image

    Mat img_hist_equalized;
    equalizeHist(image, img_hist_equalized); //equalize the histogram

    //create windows
    //namedWindow("Original Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    namedWindow("output", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    //show the image
    //imshow("Original Image", image);
    imshow("output", img_hist_equalized);
    waitKey(0); //wait for key press
    imwrite("../output.jpg", img_hist_equalized); // save image
    //cvSaveImage("output.jpg", img);

    destroyAllWindows(); //destroy all open windows

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the correct rights for file access? Maybe the file is opened elsewhere?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html

Answer (score 0):

This code segment works fine for me, finally the result image got saved.. Binaries might have got corrupted in your case, So better to rebuild the opencv library.

Comment: Thanx ... for some reason imwrite is not read in opencv2.4.5, I had to build the project with opencv2.4.8 and it worked fine